# Using Pymunk with matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation()

Tags: python, matplotlib, pymunk

i'm tring to modify [this tutorial](https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/examples/newtons_cradle.ipynb) for using matplotlib_util module (FuncAnimation). When i try to run the code below, i get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sn8L.png). I tried to add "ax.clear()" inside the animate function but then I couldn't see anything. I couldn't find the reason.

I couldn't find any samples that use "Pymuyk" and "Matplotlib FuncAnimation" together, either. if you know any examples could you please share with us.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

import pymunk
from pymunk.vec2d import Vec2d
import pymunk.matplotlib_util

def setup_space():
    space = pymunk.Space()
    space.gravity = 0,-9820
    space.damping = 0.99
    return space

def setup_balls(space):
    width = 600
    height = 600
    for x in range(-100,150,50):
        x += width / 2
        offset_y = height/2
        mass = 10
        radius = 25
        moment = pymunk.moment_for_circle(mass, 0, radius, (0,0))
        body = pymunk.Body(mass, moment)
        body.position = x, -125+offset_y
        body.start_position = Vec2d(body.position)
        shape = pymunk.Circle(body, radius)
        shape.elasticity = 0.9999999
        space.add(body, shape)
        pj = pymunk.PinJoint(space.static_body, body, (x, 125+offset_y), (0,0))
        space.add(pj)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 600), ylim=(0, 600))
ax.set_aspect("equal")

space = setup_space()
setup_balls(space)

o = pymunk.matplotlib_util.DrawOptions(ax)

space.shapes[1].body.apply_impulse_at_local_point((-12000, 0))

def init():
    space.debug_draw(o)
    return []

def animate(dt):
    #ax.clear()
    for x in range(10):
        space.step(1 / 50 / 10 / 2)

    space.debug_draw(o)
    return space,

frames = 30
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=frames, interval=20, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: It might a pymunk issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-setting xlim and ylim. It seems like at least when I use `%matplotlib notebook` magic `ax.clear()` also clears the xlim and ylim (I dont have ffmpeg to try the exact newtons code right now). So the reason nothing is shown is because the x and y axis are 0,1 and not 0,600.

So, try something like this:

```
ax.clear()
ax.set_xlim(0,600)
ax.set_ylim(0,600)
```

Note that the matplotlib helper class in pymunk is quite basic and more of a proof of concept. Depending on your needs you might get better result by plotting the space/shapes "manually".

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The movement is not smooth but I think it's not about my question, maybe because of timestep or drawing definitions.

Comment: Yeah, the slowness is a consequence of how the drawing works. Currently it redraws everything from scratch, but it would be much faster if the drawn objects could be saved between frames. Unfortunately I dont think its possible to fix as long as `pymunk.matplotlib_util` shares base drawing code with the other drawing backends in pymunk.